# event notification in Java

Tags: java, events

In java, I feed very confused on observer pattern or JMS. I want to use the event notification like below. **Let us forget about those JMS or Observer**, do you think it is possible or doable ? if yes, how to complete it ?

```
newSalesOrder = new SalesOrder();
newSalesOrder.notified("new SalesOrder order ID="+orderId);

EventRegister.bindEvent(SalesOrder.class, Delivery.class);
EventRegister.bindEvent(SalesOrder.class, Warehouse.class);

////////////
Delivery delivery = new Delivery();
delivery.listerning(new Event(source){
  if(source == SalesOrder.class){

  }  
});

//////////
Warehouse warehouse = new Warehouse();
warehouse.listerning(new Event(source){
  if(source == SalesOrder.class){

  }  
});

///////////
EventRegister{
    static bindEvent(Class source, Class destination){
      //???
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't really described what you want properly.  You've just given some method signatures, but no real indication of the behaviour you want from them (or even where your "events" come from)...

Comment: And why the seemingly arbitrary restriction to not allow the use of the Observer Pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You need to register (bind) objects not classes. You can keep registration list static at EventRegister but I think it's better to keep them as instance at SalesOrder. So it would be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SalesOrder mySalesOrder = new SalesOrder();

        Warehouse myWarehouse = new Warehouse();
        mySalesOrder.addListener(myWarehouse);

        Delivery myDelivery = new Delivery();
        mySalesOrder.addListener(myDelivery);

        Event myEvent = new Event();
        // Now 'myDelivery' and 'myWarehouse' objects will receive 'myEvent'
        // object on their 'onEvent(Event event)' method
        System.out.println("Event to be published: " + myEvent);
        mySalesOrder.publishEvent(myEvent);
    }
}

interface Listener {
    public void onEvent(Event event);
}

class Event {
    // Add reqired detail here!
}

class SalesOrder {
    private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

    public void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    // Use proper access modifier
    public void publishEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println(this + " is goint to publish " + event
                + " to " + listeners + " listeners.");
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onEvent(event);
        }
    }

    // ...
}

class Warehouse implements Listener {
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        // Do something when event received
        System.out.println(event + " received at " + this);
    }
    // ...
}

class Delivery implements Listener {
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        // Do something when event received
        System.out.println(event + " received at " + this);
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you run it it will print something like:

> Event to be published: Event@190d11
>
> SalesOrder@a90653 is goint to publish Event@190d11 to [Warehouse@de6ced, Delivery@c17164] listeners.
>
> Event@190d11 received at Warehouse@de6ced
>
> Event@190d11 received at Delivery@c17164

This is a trivial sample, in real life use cases you may consider using a thread-safe implementation and refactoring registration out of SalesOrder using composition or inheritance.